# How to write gexf graph from python igraph?

Tags: python, igraph

I'm trying to write a vertex clustered graph as a gexf file from python-igraph. Any idea how to do it? I'm aware that I can write other formats [[http://www.cs.rhul.ac.uk/home/tamas/development/igraph/tutorial/tutorial.html#igraph-and-the-outside-world]](http://www.cs.rhul.ac.uk/home/tamas/development/igraph/tutorial/tutorial.html#igraph-and-the-outside-world%5d) , but I'd like it to be gexf. There is a pygexf package but not documented well yet

Answer (score 1):

It seems python-igraph doesn't support to read a gexf file. Here is the document of Graph.Read()
[Graph.Read()](http://pythonhosted.org/python-igraph/igraph.Graph-class.html#Read)

But you can transform gexf file to other format which are supported in igraph, such as gml file,  with other tools like gephi.

Comment: Yes, but i don't want to read a gexf, I want to write out one. I want to know if I can use another library to do this.

Comment: Oh, I see. To my knowledge, pygexf is the only choice. See [gexf](http://gexf.net/format/) on the right side. [lxml](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/lxml) , the xml engine, and [pygexf](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/pygexf/0.2.2)  will be needed.  And the [document](http://pythonhosted.org//pygexf/index.html) is very simple. But I think it can satisfy most of the requirement.

Comment: Exactly I've pygexf setup, but it's not good enough. Maybe I'll try to extend it, but that's not my prime focus. I was trying to find if there was another way. May a gephi programmatic API?

Comment: A gephi API can do that, and Gephi is more focused on Java. There is another network platform support gexf file called NetworkX which is developed in Python.

Comment: And you can write from igraph into networkx. Probably from there to Gephi @ramgo